# How to Copy table to another table in sql server Without loosing Id numbers?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 table that I want copy 1thtable to 2th table .I have a Id field that is incremental and not nullable and key.
I want source table copy to destination table but I don't want Id number lossing sort.for example If id starts In source table from 102  In destination table also started from 102.
Consider destination table is empty.

How can I do it ?

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table2 ON  Insert.. select.. SET IDENTITY_INSERT table2 OFF`

Comment: what is instead of .. after Insert and select ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn identity insert on whilst transferring the data.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTable ON

Insert 2thTable
(columns)
select * from 1thTable

SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTable OFF
```

Comment: why has error and get red underline in 2thtable,1thtable and (columns) ?

Comment: Cannot find the object "IdentityTable" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.